# Could someone turn this table into a latex table?

Tags: tables

I have this table on Word and I would like to convert it to a latex table. The only thing is I don't know how to create rows that have 2 lines.

If someone could just give me the code to make this table a latex table, I'd really appreciate it!

[image]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 $(x)_2 = n$; $n\%5$  & $(x0)_2 = 2n$; $2n\%5$ & $(x1)_2 = 2n + 1$; $(2n+1)\%5$ \\ 
 \hline
 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 2 & 4 & 0 \\
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 4 & 3 & 4 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: If you really want to duplicate that layout, just leave off the `\hline` between rows. But I'd recommend getting rid of most of the rules entirely. See http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs

Comment: OK, so please give us the code you've got for the table and somebody will be happy to adapt it to show you how to use `multirow` or `p{}` or similar. But @PaulGessler 's suggestion is better (either of them) in this case.

Comment: @cfr Alrighty. I've added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to split the heading into two rows with no line between them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 $(x)_2 = n$ & $(x0)_2 = 2n$ & $(x1)_2 = 2n + 1$ \\ 
$n\%5$  & $2n\%5$ & $(2n+1)\%5$ \\ 
\hline
 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 2 & 4 & 0 \\
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 4 & 3 & 4 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Many are likely to suggest that you should follow the advice from the `booktabs` package and dispense with the vertical rules and most of the horizontal rules, which aren´t doing much more than distracting the eyes in so simple a table. Note also how the spacing between rows tends to be better by default as well (especially around the `\hline`s).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ ccc } 
 \toprule
 $(x)_2 = n$ & $(x0)_2 = 2n$ & $(x1)_2 = 2n + 1$ \\ 
$n\%5$  & $2n\%5$ & $(2n+1)\%5$ \\ 
\midrule
 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 2 & 4 & 0 \\
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 4 & 3 & 4 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```